# Connecting to a remote machine through client-server

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp, client-server, ip

I have created a simple tcp client-server application in vb.net. Everything works fine when i set *local host* (127.0.0.1) as the ip address. I wish to make a connection to a remote machine (keeping client at my machine and server on the other - or vice versa).

EDIT:

ok, the code of interest is as follows:

the server:

Dim server As TcpListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port)

the client:

Dim theip As IPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
client = New TcpClient(theip.ToString, port)

Now, what should i enter in "TextBox1.Text" if i have my client on a remote machine (connected over internet) and server at a different computer (whose external IP address is known)?
Can i enter the external IP address of the machine running the server directly in the text box? Also, do i need to take care of things like "port forwarding" / "let firewall allow the connection" and all? If yes, can you please guide me or link a tutorial so that my application does this automatically or is there an alternative approach to achieve this and so that port forward is not required? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're connecting over internet, port forwarding IS a must, like for all network connections, so the appropriate machine responds to the appropriate port. When connecting on a LAN, you just need to allow outgoing on the client and incoming connections on the server on the firewall. There is no way your program can setup those, it's completely outside of your app responsibilities to do so.
You should put clear documentation or guidelines for the user to perform those steps on both PCs. A "test connection" button may help for troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks for the help Alejandro!, i have a question though - how do application like utorrent and teamviewer work? They never ask user to port forward...

Comment: Teamviewer makes only outgoing connections from both sides, and their server manages the connection, so they don't require port forwarding (but DOES need outgoing firewall permissions on the port it uses).
UTorrent **does** needs port forwarding on your side in fact, and it offers a test for that, because being a peer-to-peer protocol, it listens for connections for seeding, and while it may work without it, it just lets you download, making Bittorrent inneficient.
The only thing I think you can do to avoid port forwarding from the users is to host the server part yourself.

Comment: ok - you explained it very well Alejandro! Thanks a lot buddy! Ok so if i make one of my systems - always available and port-forward just on this system, i can redirect traffic b/w different clients, right?
and yes - how can i plus rep you? (or make this a valid answer?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say the other machine has an *external* ip address. This implies it also has a *local* ip address; ie it is behind a NAT firewall or similar. In this case, you will have to configure the firewall to allow communication to take place, eg by setting up port forwarding.
Applications such as MSN Messenger, VOIP clients etc have elaborate mechanisms to negotiate this automatically, but they're often not very successful.

Comment: i have edited the question buddy, is there an alternative approach which doesn't require port forwarding? How should i proceed? Thanks!

Comment: What you are trying to do - to connect through the firewall from outside to inside - is exactly what the firewall is designed to prevent. So it's not easy. AFAIK MSN etc can get round this to some extent by having a server which both clients can make *outgoing* connections to, at least initially. Exactly what's required also depends on the kind of firewall in use, and those apps have some ability to identify the firewall type, and multiple strategies to get through. But if you've ever struggled to set up VOIP clients etc, you'll know it's still hit and miss.

Comment: all i need to know is - cant a normal user create an application in vb which is legit and two instances of which when run on two different remote machines, is allowed to freely communicate with each other? If wish to achieve this, how should i proceed?

Comment: Port forwarding is your best bet. When you say 'which is legit' well port forwarding is the way you tell the system that it *is* legit. Otherwise it's not straightforward, to say the least, to produce something that can just be installed and just work on any firewall setup. As I said the f/w will block i/c connections; that's what it's for. So you have to find a way to make an o/g connection *at both ends*, eg to a server. Really, anything beyond port forwarding is way beyond the scope of a SO question IMO.

Comment: thanks for the help peterG, anyways just curious to know - how do application like utorrent and teamviewer work? They never ask user to port forward!

Comment: typically a firewall will allow an o/g packet and then allow an i/c packet which appears to be a reply within a short period of time, (especially if it appears to be a request to port 80 ie to request a webpage) whereas an i/c packet which appears to be unsolicited will be blocked. Also as I said, also many apps have complex ways of detecting the firewall strategy and attempting to get round it, but these always have limitations, also it's subject to what rules have been applied on the firewall. Not many of us can use  utorrent from work, for eg.